Get Symfony configs from file without using Symfony
This config file is from a Symfony 6.4 application:
<?php

namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator;

return static function (ContainerConfigurator $containerConfig): void 
{
    $scrapePatterns = [
        'default' => [
            'regex' => '/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/i',
            'first_only' => false,
            'cancel' => false,
        ],
    ];

    $templates = [
        'header' => 'Some header',
        'footer' => 'Some footer',
    ];

    $containerConfig->parameters()->set(
        'my.sample_configs',
        [
            'scrape_patterns' => $scrapePatterns,
            'templates' => $templates,
        ]
    );
};


How can I read those definition arrays from a different PHP app that does not use Symfony at all?
I don't have the ContainerConfigurator class... I was wondering if I can create my own class with that name and use it to get the values.
A few notes about my (admittedly hacky) question:

I'm not looking for answers explaining better ways to put the problem, although I fully understand they exist; I am more interested in the actual hacky challenge as described here.
I can make changes to the Symfony config file as long as the real Symfony app is still able to load it correctly.
one of the things that is confusing me is that, due to my technical limitations, I don't understand how Symfony uses that return static function, so it's hard for me to know how to invoke this, or even the limits of what can be done with this code. I think it's done here, though I am not certain.


Can the different php app use composer ?

It is not at all clear what sort of information this "other app" needs. The config system has quite a few moving parts. If you just need a couple of key value pairs then put them in a yaml file and load them in.

@DylanKAS yes. @ yivi I did state that I don't have access to that class. Sorry if I wasn't clear. @ Cerad my idea (apart from learning PHP better) is to get those key/values from that source, without the need to duplicate them in another format or another place. But yes, I only need to cover this kind of simple configuration file that sets a few arrays. @ all thanks for your comments :-)

After understanding what Symfony was doing to run the function, I am able to answer my own question. Not as hard as I thought.
I change the code like this:
<?php

namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator;

return static function (ContainerConfigurator $containerConfig = null): array {
    $scrapePatterns = [
        'default' => [
            'regex' => '/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/i',
            'first_only' => false,
            'cancel' => false,
        ],
    ];

    $templates = [
        'header' => 'Some header',
        'footer' => 'Some footer',
    ];

    $configs = [
        'scrape_patterns' => $scrapePatterns,
        'templates' => $templates,
    ];

    if ($containerConfig) {
        $containerConfig->parameters()->set('my.sample_configs', $configs);
    }

    return $configs;
};

The changes are:

allow the function argument to be missing (null)
return an array instead of void
check if $containerConfig exists before using it (it exists when called from Symfony, doesn't exist when called from elsewhere)
return the arrays I want (Symfony doesn't seem to have any problems with this)

Then my code on the other app only needs this:

   $fn = include 'path/to/the/symfony/configs/processor_configs.php';

   if ($fn)
      $ret = $fn();

include, just like require, doesn't just execute the code, it evaluates the code. This means that the code results in a value you can store in a variable. In this case, that return static function makes the included code return a function (a closure), which can then be invoked.
This way I can get the arrays on my app, and Symfony is also able to successfully load that same configuration file.
